# Not able to clear the bin mode handler Image::Grab in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to grab all the images in the webpage using this program. But when I run this program I was getting the same image 10 times instead of different ones. I think the problem was with bin mode or the print statement "$pic->image" which was not able to clear the old contents of file handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl
# pics.pl

# Grabs multiple images from a webpage

use Image::Grab;

$pic = new Image::Grab;

# Specify the total no of pages
$totalpages = 1;
$idx2 = 1;
$idx3 = 10;

for($idx = 1; $idx <= $totalpages; $idx++)
{
  $idx4 = 1;
  $pic->regexp(".*\.jpg");
  $pic->search_url("http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/Recycling_g385.html");
  for ($idx2 = $idx2; $idx2 <= $idx3; $idx2++)
  {
    $pic->index('$idx4');
    $pic->grab;
    $name = 'image'.$idx2.'.jpg';
    open(IMAGE, ">$name") || die "$name: $!";
    binmode (IMAGE);  
    print IMAGE $pic->image;
    close (IMAGE);
    $idx4++;
  }
  $idx3 = $idx2+10;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `'$idx4'` is zero in a numeric context. You might have noticed this if you had `warnings` turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put *$idx4* here *$pic->index('$idx4');* inside single quotes. Also, please use *strict* & *warnings* pragmas in your scripts, this will help you debug easily.